# Recognition of dates via text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am building a Calendar-like application in Rails. One of the ideas was to have text describing the occurrence of an event can be parsed and understood by the app.

For example, Event A occurs "Every Friday", "Every other day", "Every week", etc.

Is there a library, or known way of implementing this?

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search revealed [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic). It has close to a million downloads on [its rubygems.org page](http://rubygems.org/gems/chronic), so I'd say it's worth checking out.

Comment: yeah, I saw this, looks pretty good, but it isnt quite what I want. The Chronic gem lets you obtain specific dates, rather than a re-occurrence of events. For example, I do not think Chronic understands the concept of "Every Friday" for example.